# How to update subdocument into an array using MongoDB in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I'm using **Codeigniter 3.0.6**, with this **MongoDB Library** https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library

What i'm trying to do is to update fields in a subdocument of this following **committees** array with **ObjectId("570f6e08407729ec3000002b")**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("570f4a94407729d42e00002e"),
"name" : "Test Community",
"committees" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("570f6e08407729ec3000002b"),
        "name" : "2016",
        "start" : ISODate("2016-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "end" : ISODate("2016-12-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "join_state" : 1,
        "state" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("570f6e08407729ec3000002c"),
        "name" : "2017",
        "start" : ISODate("2017-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "end" : ISODate("2017-12-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "join_state" : 1,
        "state" : 1
    }
]}
```

But using above library or can you suggest me some other way to make it work right. Please **don't** mention mongodb command lines, as i'm aware about it. So it would be great if you can help me with **PHP** code, or **codeigniter** way is very much appreciable.

Comment: db.collection.update( {"committes.name":2015}, 
                    { $set : { committes.$.name: 2016} }, false, true ); pls try this code in mongodb

Comment: Complementing comment above you want to use [$ as positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), don't know if/how CI lib supports it but it's perfectly doable using plain PHP driver.

Comment: @msvairam that works fine when Im communicating with mongodb through mongod editor. But in CI it kind of didn't work. So, I have modified my  current CI mongodb library. So that I can have more parameters for $set function. And so now it works fine.